Is there a way to generate an env file with github actions and pass it directly to docker and/or elastic beanstalk?
I'm looking for a way to create/generate an env file so that Docker Cloud Build or AWS Elastic Beanstalk (via CodePipeline) can pull them directly from the repository after a github action that generates an env file.
I know that most if not all hosting servers have their own way of managing environment variables, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for it to be generated by github action before being pushed into AWS CodePipeline or Docker Cloud Build so that there's only one file to touch when changing configs.
I've found that its mostly preferred that env variables are set-up manually on the servers for security purposes, but my target here is mostly for test servers, and self-hosted servers (docker) for personal use, so security is not top priority; but at the same time, I'm exploring to have it generated by github action (or something else, if there's a different option that can support both Docker and AWS) instead of pushing the .env file directly to the repository.
I have a github action under .github/workflows/generate-env.yml
name: generate-env

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "test"

jobs:
  generate_env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Generate env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo "${{ vars.APP_ENV }}" >> .env
          cat .env

It generates and shows the .env contents correctly, but Docker and CodePipeline is not able to pull it
Looking forward to suggestions

show an example of the part where you attempt to access .env

Hi @erik258, I do not have any code after generating the .env file aside from pushing it to docker cloud build. I assumed that once I generate the .env file with github action, docker or codepipeline would be able to pull it along with the generated .env file.
Does that mean any file generated with github action will not necessarily reflect to whatever is pulling the repository? So I have to store it somewhere else, and pull that file during build on CodePipeline or Docker?

If you want it to be pulled with the repo as in a git pull, then you'd have to add it in a new commit and then tell the next build step(s) to use that commit instead of the source commit.

@erik258, but if I commit the .env file, wouldn't that defeat the target of having it generated with github action instead of pushing it directly into the repository?

Yes, exactly.  Besides, you want your commit of the code to be used as the source for all the downstream jobs.  Instead, you'll have to host that.env file somewhere that the docker build can access it.  It makes more sense to access it at runtime.

I don't believe it is necessary to put .env in a commit. You can have a copy of this file on your local machine and save the entire file as a Secret Variable in your project repository. It was the solution I used in some of my projects. You can also pass this variable as an argument to a script called within your workflow. I answered below by writing a solution that sends the file to the server.

Hi @GeraldoNovais. That does sound right. I might just have to manually add the env values as arguments for docker. Im just concerned it will not fit with the EB server. But if there's really no way to it, I'll just run 2 different jobs to accommodate both scenarios. Or find a service that can hold the values so I can just pull them during build.

Yes, it's possible.
The code below generates an env file with github actions and pass it directly to the server
Once the file is on the server, it can be used by Docker or some script as environment variables.
name: Send .env file to production sever
    
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    
    jobs:
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Checkout repository
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
          - name: Install SSH key
            uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
            with:
              ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    
          - name: Create a .env file
            env:
              ENV_FILE: ${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}
            run: |
              echo "$ENV_FILE" > .env
    
          - name: Transfer .env file to production server
            run: scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no .env ${{ secrets.PRODUCTION_SERVER_USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.PRODUCTION_SERVER_DOMAIN }}:/path/to/project/folder/
            env:
              SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY }}

The step "creates a .env file" assigns the value of the secret ENV_FILE to the environment variable ENV_FILE and then echoes this value into the .env file.
The next step uses scp to send the .env file to the remote server.
The variables used have self-explanatory names. They must be added before in your Github repository settings:
settings > secrets and variables > actions


Hi. Thanks for the tip. However, I'm a little doubtful this will work on my scenario. Because after generating the .env file, it will push through to the docker cloud build (which will make a new build, so I cant send the generated .env file via SCP), and in the case of Elastic Beanstalk, it will generate a new build (so if I do send the .env file to the server, it will be overwritten and vanish once the new build completes). This may work if I host the .env file somewhere else and just pull it during build of the image. Im just not sure where that safe storage can be.

There's a number of reasons not to do this.  You'll need your server to be open to github actions runners on port 22 and you'll have to distribute a key to do so.   In addition to what's shown here, you'd have to somehow get the file into the docker container's filesystem (to be fair, that could be as simple as a mounted volume - if your runtime environment supports that.). Anyway, this is still an example of delivering your configuration essentially outside the build process - which in my answer, I'm encouraging you to do.

Right, this can be easy enough to do on an AWS server, but probably not with docker. I guess there's no one size fits all answer to this. Unless I find a service that will hold the .env values and just pull it during build process via ebextension or entrypoint.


I know that most if not all hosting servers have their own way of managing environment variables

This is the way to do it.  You're already storing your config settings in vars.APP_ENV.  Just store them somewhere else, somewhere that easily integrates with your hosting.

but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for it to be generated by github action before being pushed into AWS CodePipeline or Docker Cloud Build

You can generate it there, but merely generating it in the temporary storage of a github action won't automatically make it available to other build jobs that pull the same commit source from github.
Also, this means that you have to rerun the build jobs to change environment variables.
That's why instead of storing it in vars.APP_ENV, you should store it in cloud storage somewhere convenient for your program to access it.  Then you can just update your deployments or restart your servers.

so that there's only one file to touch when changing configs.

There can always be one "thing" to touch when changing configs.  It doesn't have to be vars.APP_ENV.
My suggestion would be SSM Parameter Store from AWS.  You're already in AWS.  https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-use-env-variables describes one way to import them at initialization time.  This doesn't seem like a particularly compelling approach to me.  Other hosting options on AWS make this easier - Fargate might also be cheaper, and easier in other ways.  I consider Elastic Beanstalk to be previous generation technology.
Another option would be to essentially move the github action to an initialization step in your Dockerfile's entrypoint, whichwould subsequently invoke your program.  You can grant Parameter Store access to the application's role, then make a call to Parameter Store and redirect the output to your .env.  This is simple and straight forward.

Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look into this. Somehow I feel like the best way is to really just find a service that will hold the contents of the .env file for me and just pull it up during the build process via .ebextensions (for EB) and via entrypoint (for Docker).

I've been doing this for many years, before and after Docker rose to prominence.  Resolving environment variables at runtime is the way to do it.  Good luck.  Open a new question if you run into further issues
